# How get 14.04 LTS to recognise camera on a Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I've completely removed OS-X and installed 14.04. Everything else works fine but the camera is not recognized and does not appear anywhere in the System Settings menus.
Is there a switch to be thrown?

Thanks.

The Model is  A1278    SN:W8004A2Q66D

Thanks again.

Comment: MacBook model would be helpful :)